# Web page redirect and issue with browser button

Tags: php

I have a PHP data entry page and redirecting to the new page after data inserted successfully. But the user can go back using the Browser back button and click on the 'Save' button again. Is there any way I can prevent this kind of problem? Please suggest. Thank you.

I am using the following code to redirect.

```
header ("location:Redirect.php?ref=10");
```

Comment: Do you have some way of uniquely identifying the data being submitted to check if it's already been submitted?  Even if you put in some hack to hijack the back button (please don't), you can't stop the user from submitting the form multiple times, either by accident or by malicious design.

Comment: What's stopping them from just refreshing the page and resubmitting the data a second time?

I'd track a cookie or session variable with a unique 'key' to allow posting, to stop resubmission and display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can store a variable in their session whenever they click the button then use this to show/hide the button accordingly by checking that session variable. Also if it's set then do not allow posting/processing of the form.

Comment: What if the browser renders the page from cache with the button visible?  What if the user double-clicks the button and posts twice?  What if the user captures the POST with a debugging tool and re-submits it over and over in a loop?

Comment: Then check the session variable before processing post data.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying now.  Disallow from a form-handling perspective, not from a form-displaying perspective.  Makes sense.